# ConditionalOnMissingBean by class and name

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to create bean when specific class type with specific name is missing, but `ConditionalOnMissingBean` below does not work, since value and name are not related.

```
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(value=BeanName.class, name = "beanName")
```

Comment: why can't you just give name and remove value attribute?

Comment: @pvpkiran  The name may be shared with another class type.

Comment: Then you better change that, having same name for classes of different types doesn't look like a nice thing to do

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just wander if there is a way to achieve this.

Comment: `@ConditionalOnSingleCandidate` may be suitable in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such functionality of the box. However, you can easily implement it with custom [Conditional](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html):

```
class MyCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {

      String[] beanNames = context.getBeanFactory().getBeanNamesForType(BeanName.class);

      return Stream.of(beanNames).anyMatch(beanName -> beanName.equals("beanName"));
    }
  }
```

and add it to your bean `@Conditional(MyCondition.class)`